# How do I use the MagicPython syntax highlighting with latex?

Tags: listings, python, syntax-highlighting

I would like to use the syntax highlighting from MagicPython with LaTeX - preferably with the listings package.

According to the documentation for the listings package it should be possible to supply a .prf file to overrule the standard python syntax highlighting with listings, but is there even such a thing as a preference file for the MagicPython package?

If this is not possible, is the only way of having syntax highlighting in the github/magicpython-style to define my own language?